# C# Make Usercontrol draggable

Tags: c#, wpf, scheduler, appointment

Currently I'm working on a Scheduler-Control for my Application. The Scheduler is a Grid with specified Columns and Rows. For my Appointments I've created a Usercontrol with this Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Testprokekt.Appointment"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testprokekt"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <StackPanel x:Name="contentPanel">
        <TextBlock x:Name="titleBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
</UserControl>
```

This works perfectly and I get no Problems. 
But now I want to be able to drag these Appointments inside the Scheduler(Grid). Is there a way to do it?

The Scheduler Looks like this: Every Cell is a Grid Cell.
[image]

Comment: Surely https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh144799(v=vs.110).aspx applies, it just so happens that the start and end are the same control

Comment: @BugFinder thank you. Is there a way to make the Appointments snapping to the grid, so that they cant be placed everywhere, only at the gridlines?

Comment: something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282443/drag-and-drop-custom-controls-between-cells-in-a-grid-in-wpf ? I take it your google-fu is lacking

Comment: yeah Google is down for me :D just a joke, didn't find it

Comment: all I googled was "wpf drag drop align c#"

Comment: If you want to make it draggable, I would suggest you put the target (draggable) objects inside a Canvas :) Canvas are just like a grid but with much less complexity (which actually runs faster than a grid, but you don't get all the juicy stuff from a grid) And then you can adjust the objects exact position by using Canva.Top="Desired Y-Pos" Canvas.Left="Desired X-Pos", these can be bound or you can use `objectToMove.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newPositionY);  objectToMove.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newPositionX);` from code-behind

Comment: @KarlPatrikJohansson thanks. But with a canvas, I have to know the right coordinates to place the items. Got it to work with a grid and my UserControls, but had a little work to do like Collision with other Appointments. :)

Comment: @F.Baum Yes indeed :-P it might not be as graceful solution as the one BugFinder suggested. However it does give you full control over the solution! For collision you'd do box collision detection and for grid snapping you determine the mouse over cell/or cells within the "box collider" and just align the Appointment block automatically :D

Comment: @KarlPatrikJohansson Yes, did it right like you explained it :D