# Is there a way of easily putting an object into a grid with Drag and Drop?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mvvm

At the moment I have no Idea how to start this. I created a blank UserControl in WPF. My Window looks like this at the moment:

[image]

The List on the right is a ListView. I want to Drag and Drop an Item of the List (Not the topic, asking that in another question soon). When i drop it on the white space, I want the Image to get drawn where I dropped it.

But I don't want it only to be an Image, in general, this Program is for creating a setup by drag and dropping the Modules on the right and create a configuration with the setup you've built in the big plain space. This image may make that more clear:

[image]

These Images need to be able to rearranged at any time, so I don't think I just need to draw them, I need to place an Object on the Work-place. Imagine it like Windows Forms, where you drag and drop your tools, rearrange them and be able to zoom in and out. I don't need the Zoom feature yet, but it's going to be in there too. Is there maybe a nuget that I can use for implementing a "Drawing-Board"?

Comment: Maybe you should start without any d&d... just create your view in a way where it displays the contents of a viewmodel list, where each item contains information about its placement etc. Afterwards, a drop will mostly consist of creating an appropriate item and adding it to the VM items list

Comment: I'm not sure about the "easily" part of this, but I know how to do what you want. It's quite a long subject to cover in detail though.  As a result not really suitable for a SO post if you're looking for detail and code. List of stuff you need to know... bit of explanation I could do that.  I wouldn't recommend any nuget. I find this is one of those things I'm best writing my own code.

Comment: Look at this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282443/drag-and-drop-custom-controls-between-cells-in-a-grid-in-wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282443/drag-and-drop-custom-controls-between-cells-in-a-grid-in-wpf). May be useful.

Comment: @Andy I'd really appreciate if you could help me with it. I'm learning C# for about a year now, I have many Ideas, and I try to realize them to learn new stuff whenever I can. This project just came in my mind, I started and now I stuck at this part

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn you should be more specific on what you need help with... some people have problems to drop anything, because they didn't assign a background to their drop target or whatever... how can we know what your specific problem is, instead of writing the whole thing for you?

Comment: Not writing it. I just don't know how to start. So what kind of class do I need to use, so I can drop Objects freely on it? Then I know how to continue, cause I can't find anything of an object-DrawingPad

Comment: You can drop objects basically anywhere... any `UIElement` or `ContentElement` can be linked to a Drop-Handler. Did you already complete *any* drag-drop code sample (like https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-enabling-drag-and-drop-on-a-user-control) before trying to drag-drop UI elements with specific positioning?

Comment: Are you sure that a grid is the right target for this? Wouldn't a Canvas be better when you want to pixel positioning?