# Checkers and movable figures WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing simple checkers game in C# and WPF. The problem i am facing has to do with displaying properly the content. I've got  a board, i can put pawns wherever I want on it, but unfortunately I cannot make any figure move (My vision is that player clicks on Pawn/Queen - the figure is now movable with cursor - then he puts it on right spot). I tried removing Image from parent and adding to different grid and some other ideas - however I failed.

```
<Window x:Class="Checkers.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Checkers"
    Title="Checkers" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" MinWidth="800" MinHeight="680"  Width="800" Height="680" Icon="C:\Users\NAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Checkers\Checkers\Resources\package_games_board.ico" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Pawn}">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" MouseDown="ItemsControl_MouseDown_1" MouseMove="helo_MouseMove_1" Name="helo" Tag="{Binding Reference}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="MidnightBlue">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="600"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="600" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <UniformGrid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="CheckersBoard" Rows="8" Columns="8"  SnapsToDevicePixels="False"/>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="GridBoard">
                    <Grid IsItemsHost="True">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Then I have class of Pawn:

```
public class Pawn : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public bool IsBlack { get; set; }

    public Pawn Reference { get; set; }
    private int _row;
    public Pawn()
    {
        Reference = this;
    }

    public int Row
    {
        get { return _row; }
        set
        {
            _row = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Row");
        }
    }

    private int _column;
    public int Column
    {
        get { return _column; }
        set
        {
            _column = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Column");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string ImageSource 
    {
        get { return "C:\\Users\\NAME\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Checkers\\Checkers\\Resources\\" + (IsBlack ? "black" : "white") + "_transparent.png"; }
    }

}
```

And the main code (rest is not the case):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Pawn> Pawns;
    private void ShowBoard()
    {
        SolidColorBrush scb_white = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#8080FF"));
        SolidColorBrush scb_dark = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#004A95"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            CheckersBoard.Children.Add(new Rectangle() { Name = "field"+i, Stroke=Brushes.Black, Fill = (i + 1 + i / 8) % 2 == 0 ? scb_white : scb_dark });

        Pawns.Add(new Pawn() { Row = 0, Column = 0, IsBlack = true });
        Pawns.Add(new Pawn() { Row = 0, Column = 2, IsBlack = false });
        Pawns.Add(new Pawn() { Row = 0, Column = 4, IsBlack = true });
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Pawns = new ObservableCollection<Pawn>();
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = Pawns;
        ShowBoard();
    }

    Mouse handlers ...
```

Does someone know the solution?

Comment: About the real movement concept: 
I don't know how to assign mouse position to grid column and row and how to avoid the problem that I can only move inside the specific grid row and column (field).

Or maybe i did not get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the code you have, just setting Row/Column on the Pawn object *appears* like it would perform the "movement" you want. Check the output window for binding exceptions if it isn't working.

That being said, that will just make them all jump around. For true **movement** you will need to write Storyboards (likely in code-behind) and move their positions around. The best way to do that is via TranslateTransform.

**Update**

Doing drag and drop in this kind of system is going to be very difficult and not terribly efficient. You may want to look at this question/answer: [Dragging a WPF user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284056/dragging-a-wpf-user-control)