# 'MouseEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'GetPosition'

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

Im sure this is a super easy one but I am working on a C# UWP app and am trying to make a drag-able user control but in my mouse event I'm getting the following error:

CS1061  'MouseEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'GetPosition' and no extension method 'GetPosition' accepting a first argument of type 'MouseEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I found this example I am using on stack ([Dragging a WPF user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284056/dragging-a-wpf-user-control)) and have used mouse down events before for dragging items between list boxes in winforms but didn't have this issue.

Here is my code:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="HopHaus.TimerControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HopHaus"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400" Width="120" Height="60">

    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,167" Width="120">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF404040" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="1,0,-1,-133" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="timersetBox" Margin="-1,-2,1,-59" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" BorderBrush="Transparent" FontFamily="Fonts/DIGITAL.TTF#Digital" Foreground="#FF72FB00" FontSize="50" Background="Transparent" TextAlignment="Right" AcceptsReturn="True" SelectionHighlightColor="#000078D7" Width="120"/>
        <Border x:Name="dragBrdr" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="59" Margin="2,0,0,-59" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And:

```
 public sealed partial class TimerControl : UserControl
    {
        Point currentPoint;
        Point anchorPoint;
        bool isInDrag;
        public TimerControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();
        private void root_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isInDrag)
            {
                var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
                currentPoint = e.GetPosition(null);

                transform.X += currentPoint.X - anchorPoint.X;
                transform.Y += (currentPoint.Y - anchorPoint.Y);
                this.RenderTransform = transform;
                anchorPoint = currentPoint;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using both using `System.Windows.Input` & `using Windows.Devices.Input`

Thanks a bunch in advance for any help provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but am still unsure how to take my var point and transform it into a new position of my user control on my MainPage

As  @Dave Smits said you need a [`Pointer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227968) event handle. More details about handle pointer input please reference [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/handle-pointer-input).  I think what you confused is that this code `var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(null);` return [`PointerPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242038) object instead [`Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.point) structure what you needed for transform. In that case, you can get the `Point` structure by [`PointerPoint.Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.pointerpoint.position) property. Updated code as follows:

```
<UserControl
    ...
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"  
   Width="120" Height="60"  PointerMoved="Grid_PointerMoved" CanDrag="True">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,167" Width="120" >
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF404040" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="1,0,-1,-133" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="timersetBox" Margin="-1,-2,1,-59" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" BorderBrush="Transparent" FontFamily="Fonts/DIGITAL.TTF#Digital" Foreground="#FF72FB00" FontSize="50" Background="Transparent" TextAlignment="Right" AcceptsReturn="True" SelectionHighlightColor="#000078D7" Width="120"/>
        <Border x:Name="dragBrdr" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="59" Margin="2,0,0,-59" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind

```
 Point currentPoint;
 Point anchorPoint;
 bool isInDrag;
 private TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();
 private void Grid_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     anchorPoint = new Point(300, 200);
     isInDrag = true;
     if (isInDrag)
     {
         var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
         PointerPoint currentPointpointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(null);
         currentPoint = currentPointpointer.Position;
         transform.X += currentPoint.X - anchorPoint.X;
         transform.Y += (currentPoint.Y - anchorPoint.Y);
         this.RenderTransform = transform;
         anchorPoint = currentPoint;
     }
 }
```

Additionally, for transform from one point to another I recommend you to use [PointAnimation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br210346).

Comment: Thanks heaps Sunteen I understand it now and I can see the values being passed on, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

To have better support for touch and inking there is an abstraction over the mouse events. This is called pointer. So in you you have a PointerMoved event

in xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          PointerMoved="Grid_PointerMoved">

    </Grid>
```

and in code

```
    private void Grid_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(null);
    }
```

Comment: Ok great thanks, I have been reading up for the last couple of hours but am still unsure how to take my `var point` and transform it into a new position of my user control on my MainPage.